# URL to Google Maps Driving Directions View

Tags: google-maps

I want to link to a gmaps page like this:

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Nashville,+TN/33.54521,-88.20995/@34.8499835,-88.6707012,8z/am=t/data=!3m1!4b1!4m8!4m7!1m5!1m1!1s0x8864ec3213eb903d:0x7d3fb9d0a1e9daa0!2m2!1d-86.7816016!2d36.1626638!1m0

I have a starting city and an ending lat/long.  To just get the route I use this url:

https://www.google.com/maps?saddr=Nashville+TN&daddr=33.545,-88.2099

And that works fine.  But I want it to go straight to the directions view that you see in the first link.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Why the downvote?  Please explain why this is a bad question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found it.  Here it is in case anyone has the same question

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Nashville+TN/31.44853,-87.35202/@/am=t/